# Should we edit past answers to add cittation to the documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

As this new Documentation thing is on board, should we edit our past answers, including citations to the Documentation ?

Comment: Wow, folks - he seems mostly concerned with wondering if we're encouraging something or not. This is a legit question to which I'm writing an answer. Please consider your downvotes.

Comment: Personally i wouldn't until there are assurances that if something gets moved in Documentation the internal link doesn't break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had two distinctly different experiences when writing answers on Stack Overflow:

- I'm helping someone that knows less than I do understand something
- I'm helping someone that knows as much or probably more than I do solve a problem

In the cases where you're *teaching*, it might be appropriate to link to the documentation (if it exists) for the benefit of future readers. But, take care to not be too pedantic. Mentioning that it exists is different from saying *go read this*.

In the cases where you're helping someone solve a complex problem, a link to something documenting the basic parts of their problem would seem .. kind of out of place I think, in most situations.

Use your best judgement, but don't go back an edit *everything* just to surface Documentation; we're going to be working on better ways it can be surfaced after we tackle more pressing issues.